# Building PHP Extensions on Eclipse

Tags: php, c++

Is this possible? If so, can anyone lend me a helping hand? Just a tip :) thanks.

I'm fairly good at scripting but I hate engineering although I need that badly.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know `C` it's good enough. Read up on Zend Engine docs and API to know where to start. Writing a PHP extension doesn't depend on the IDE but depends on your skills.

Comment: Yeah I know that, But I'm fairly getting to know with C++, I just want to extend my PHP Functions though so that it will optimize speed, and I dont want to use HHVM or HipHop language. Also, thanks.

Comment: So you want to make your functions native for better performace? See https://wiki.php.net/internals/references for some resources